# Update-database command ignores previous migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I use `Ef core` in my project and create database structure with commands `Add-migration` and `Update-database`.

After migrating to new host I moved db too, and wanted to apply some db changes by running `update-database` command.

But instead of adding a couple of fields to one of the tables, this command had duplicated the creation of all tables with PascalCase naming ignoring migration history, that exists in "__efmigrationshistory" table.

I cannot understand why is it happening. How can it be solved?

Version of Ef core is `6.0.8`

Answer (score 0):

It solved.

My error was when I deploy mysql in docker I should use command `--lower_case_table_names=1`

```
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --lower_case_table_names=1
```